# String builder initialized length,index out of bounds error

Tags: java, stringbuilder

In the below code, I am getting the `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` in `sBuilder.insert(pos,words[i]);` line,

I have initialized the length here `new StringBuilder(s.length())` for the below input,
`System.out.println(sortSentence("is2 sentence4 This1 a3"));`

```
public static String sortSentence(String s) {

        StringBuilder sBuilder=new StringBuilder(s.length());
        String words[]= s.split(" ");

        for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
        {
           int pos= Integer.parseInt(words[i].replaceAll("\\D+",""));
           // this is the line of error
           sBuilder.insert(pos,words[i]);
        }
        return sBuilder.toString();

    }
```

This is the error I am getting,

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: offset 2, length 0`

The length of the input String is 22 how can I get this error despite of this ?

Comment: @ChetanAhirrao - It is clearly there in the question itself. Please read the question again

Comment: The *size* and *length* of a StringBuilder are two different things. One defines the (initial) capacity, and the other the length of the current content.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel In the above constructor I have defined the capacity.

Comment: The thing you're missing is that `insert` is bounded by the current *length*, not the *size* (capacity). Initially, the *length* is `0` (empty string builder), even if the *size* is `s.length()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you check the code where the exception is raised it becomes clearer. StringBuilder's content has no such index, and the capacity from the constructor doesn't fill it by default.

```
static void checkOffset(int offset, int length) {
    if (offset < 0 || offset > length) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException("offset " + offset +
                                                  ", length " + length);
    }
}
```

Also the javadoc says it:

> Inserts the string representation of the Object argument into this
> character sequence. The offset argument must be greater than or equal
> to 0, and less than or equal to the ***length*** of this sequence.
> Throws: StringIndexOutOfBoundsException – if the offset is invalid.

Note: length, not capacity, of StringBuilder, not of the input string.

For the notion that `sBuilder.setLength(s.length());` solves the problem: only if the perceived problem is the exception alone.  `setLength` initializes the internally used array with `(byte)0` btw, which gives a rather odd string as a result.

But then, why use a string builder in the first place? Just set everything in the original string to " " which is not an integer, can be done with a single regex like this one: `s.replaceAll("[^0-9]", " ")`.

Or the other way: don't insert into stringbuilder, just append, solves the problem too, maybe, depending on the interpretation.

Looks like the whole issue belongs more on a code review site, imho.

Comment: For the input "is2 sentence4 This1 a3" the length is 22, how can it throw an exception.

Comment: The other way round: not the length of the string, the length of the builder, sBuilder.length(). Sounds strange, length of the builder, but that's how it is.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand that you are simply trying to remove spaces. I may suggest to go for much simpler approach. No need to start with capacity at all.

```
public class MyClass {
    
public static String sortSentence(String s) {

        StringBuilder sBuilder=new StringBuilder();
        String words[]= s.split(" ");

        for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++)
        {
           int pos= Integer.parseInt(words[i].replaceAll("\\D+",""));
           // this is the line of error
           sBuilder.append(words[i]);
        }
        return sBuilder.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
      System.out.println(sortSentence("is2 sentence4 This1 a3"));
    }
}
```

OR

Simply use String `replaceAll()` method.